# break from a case early

Tags: mysql, case, where-clause

I have been having a terrible time with this code. I was wondering if someone could look and tell me how to either break out of the case statement if the CC_LIST contains a matching value already. It keeps concatenating and I want it check for an email address mapped by the join and then break if the email address is present. Below is my code:

```
UPDATE HD_TICKET

JOIN USER ON USER.FULL_NAME = CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11

SET HD_TICKET.CC_LIST =

CASE WHEN HD_TICKET.CC_LIST = '' OR HD_TICKET.CC_LIST IS NULL THEN USER.EMAIL 
ELSE CONCAT(HD_TICKET.CC_LIST, ", ", USER.EMAIL)
END 
where HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = 12
```

Comment: Problems like this are why you shouldn't put comma-separated lists in database columns. Join with a table that has the values in separate rows.

Comment: that is the format the field requires. it is a list of email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be for you to create a procedure or a function to do that
Because with the function you can select all users and then create the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to test if the value is already in the list. In that case, set the column to itself.

```
UPDATE HD_TICKET

JOIN USER ON USER.FULL_NAME = CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11

SET HD_TICKET.CC_LIST =
    CASE WHEN HD_TICKET.CC_LIST = '' OR HD_TICKET.CC_LIST IS NULL THEN USER.EMAIL 
         WHEN FIND_IN_SET(USER.EMAIL, REPLACE(HD_TICKET.CC_LIST, ' ', '')) THEN HD_TICKET.CC_LIST
         ELSE CONCAT(HD_TICKET.CC_LIST, ",", USER.EMAIL)
    END 
where HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = 12
```

Comment: This still allows it to append the same email over and over again.

Comment: No it doesn't. `FIND_IN_SET` is true if the email is already in the list. In that case, it doesn't append it.

Comment: Don't put a space after the comma, I don't think `FIND_IN_SET` trims spaces before matching.

Comment: this will allow it to append an adress if the there is something in the field prior to it. if the field is empty it works great. but it seems like it isnt searching far enough down the string value to get a value? 
UPDATE HD_TICKET

    JOIN USER ON USER.FULL_NAME = CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE11

    SET HD_TICKET.CC_LIST =
    CASE WHEN HD_TICKET.CC_LIST = '' OR HD_TICKET.CC_LIST IS NULL    THEN USER.EMAIL 
         WHEN FIND_IN_SET(USER.EMAIL, HD_TICKET.CC_LIST) THEN         HD_TICKET.CC_LIST
    ELSE CONCAT(HD_TICKET.CC_LIST, ",", USER.EMAIL)
    END 
    where HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = 12

Comment: Don't put long codes in comments, there's no formatting. If you want to show what you're trying, add it as an update to the question.

Comment: Please make a sqlfiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Go to sqlfiddle.com, it allows you to create a publicly accessible database for demonstration and testing purposes.

Comment: I think it is because of the space. can you show an example where it removes the spaces and commas in CC_LIST just for the search. maybe a REPLACE would work here?

Comment: I've added `REPLACE` to the answer. But this is going to make the query very expensive, since it has to convert this field in every row as it's searching. Why not remove the spaces when you store the data in the first place?

Comment: Unfortunately that is how the Dell Kace box stores the emails. Why? I do not know.